# AJAX form not interacting PHP callback

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a submit button. On clicking it,i am tryin to return a response from php call back file. But i am not getting any response. On clicking submit,i get following url

```
http://localhost/folder/new.php?submit=Submit+Query
```

PHP file-named as `new.php`

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function callme()
    {
        var req;
        try
        {
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch (e)
        {
            try
            {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (e)
            {
                try
                {
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }catch (e)
                {
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        req.onreadystatechange=function(){
                                        if(req.readyState==4)
                                        {
                                            document.getElementById("display_area").innerHTML=req.responseText;;
                                        }
                                    }
        req.open("GET","phpcall.php",true);
        req.send();

    }
</script>
```

and the PHP call back file- named as     `phpcall.php`

```
<?php
    echo "returning from phpcall.php";
?>
```

What is possibly the mistake here?? what is the reason for the url changing to

```
http://localhost/folder/new.php?submit=Submit+Query
```

Adding in the form part-

```
<form name='myForm'>
Max Age: <input type='text' id='age' /> <br />
Max WPM: <input type='text' id='wpm' />
<br />
Sex: <select id='sex'>
<option value="m">m</option>
<option value="f">f</option>
</select>
<input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' 
                              value='Query MySQL'/>
</form>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button  `type="button"` like `<input type="button" value="Submit">`. Keeping a `type="submit"` will submit the form and hence page will refresh

Comment: the `<input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Query MySQL'/>` should be `<input type='button' onclick='callme()' value='Query MySQL'/>` AND `document.getElementById("display_area").innerHTML=req.responseText;` should be `document.getElementById("ajaxDiv").innerHTML=req.responseText;;`

Answer (score 1):

When you use a submit button and form, your onclick handler must return false, or call the preventDefault method. If not, your form will submit before your XMLHttpRequest is done.

Comment: This would have been my next question to Niloy Saha...Thanks

Comment: how about using onsubmit??will that too need a similar return false?

Comment: When you attach to an event with any handler, the browser will run first your event handler code, then, if your code returns true, or nothing (so doesn't returns false), the browser will think, you did not handle the event, so if it has another handler, will run it, if not, will run the default handler, with the default functionality.
In this case and when you attach on submit with onsubmit, the default event handler in the browser will submit your form, if you don't return false, or don't call preventDefault.
This used in the form validation. The validator can attach to onsubmit, and when the

Comment: form submitted, it can check the fields, and, if it founds some error in the form, returns false and the form will not submit, otherwise returns true, and the form submits.